# Passing data to Bootstrap modal using Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I know this question has been asked before but cannot find an adequate way of doing this. What is the best practice for angular in passing data into a bootstrap modal?

There is a carousel item you can click on, then a modal supposed to pop up according to the corresponding data of the item.

Here are the codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="winit-slider-1" class="winit-slider" ng-controller="winitCtrl">
    <div class="winit-item text-center" ng-repeat="winit in winits">
        <img src="{{winit.photo}}" class="width-100">
        <h4 class="text-red">{{winit.filled}}</h4>
        <h3>{{winit.title}}</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-winit margin-bot-10">Winit!</a>
        <div class="social-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('winitApp', ["angularModalService"]);
app.controller('winitCtrl', function($scope, ModalService) {
    var winits = [
        {
            id:1, 
            photo:"https://cdnb.lystit.com/photos/1678-2015/11/04/gucci-us-beigeblue-gg-supreme-childrens-gg-supreme-backpack-beige-product-4-168315478-normal.jpeg", 
            filled:"40% Full in 3 Days", 
            title:"Olivia-Burton Women Watch"
        },
        {
            id:2, 
            photo:"http://images.bigcartel.com/product_images/122941467/fin_pegleg_brd2.jpg?auto=format&fit=max&h=1000&w=1000", 
            filled:"80% Full in 2 Days", 
            title:"Super-Cool Fast Skateboard"
        },
        {
            id:3, 
            photo:"http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/581102529_1/New-Vintage-Fashion-Gear-Handmade-Genuine-Leather-Strap-Watches-Disc-Diamond-Women-s-Wristband-Watch-Free.jpg", 
            filled:"45% Full in 8 Days", 
            title:"Most-Expensive Watch Ever"
        },
        {
            id:4, 
            photo:"https://cdnb.lystit.com/photos/1678-2015/11/04/gucci-us-beigeblue-gg-supreme-childrens-gg-supreme-backpack-beige-product-4-168315478-normal.jpeg", 
            filled:"40% Full in 3 Days", 
            title:"Olivia-Burton Women Watch"
        },
    ];

    $scope.winits = winits;

    ModalService.showModal({

    })

});
```

Comment: What data are you trying to pass in?  I don't see any data, just links, and no ng-model.

Comment: Just the image url and title. I'm wondering how I can make modals dynamic according to which item you click on. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using only bootstrap? No other angular components?

Comment: You only need to pass a model on your click.  I would tell you how if I could tell what the model is supposed to be.

Comment: If each modal contains just title and the image of the item clicked, what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesnt answer to your question, but if can add other libraries to your application.

I recommend you including Angular ui bootstrap who has a modal built with it: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal